# The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect while calling a WebService through rest using AngularJS

Tags: java, spring, web-services, angularjs

I have WebService which is checking whether the email is already present in the database.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/checkPersonEmail/{jClientSessionId}/{jClientSessionId}/{email}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public boolean checkName(@PathVariable String jUserSessionId,
        @PathVariable String jClientSessionId, @PathVariable String email)
        throws Exception {
    String decryptedClientKey = EncryptContetns
            .getDecryptedvalue(jClientSessionId);
    List<String> emailIds = dimPersonManager
            .getEmailIdsByClientKey(Long.valueOf(decryptedClientKey));
    List<String> emailIdList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String ids : emailIds) {
        emailIdList.add(ids.toLowerCase());
    }
    if (emailIdList != null && !emailIdList.isEmpty()) {
        if (emailIdList.contains(email.toLowerCase())) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Then I'm calling this service using a http.get method as show below.

**AngularJS call**

```
$scope.checkEmail = function() {
    if (!appClient.isUndefinedOrNull($scope.person.email)) {
        alert( $scope.person.email);
        $scope.spinnerClass = "icon-2x icon-spinner icon-spin";
        var serverConnect = serverUrl + 'checkPersonEmail' + '/' + jUserSessionId + '/' + jClientSessionId + '/'+ $scope.person.email;
        $http.get(serverConnect).success(function(data, status) {
            // alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            if (data == "true") {
                $scope.spinnerClass = "icon-hide";
                $scope.msgClass = "text-success icon-ok";
                $scope.message = "Available";
            } else {
                $scope.spinnerClass = "icon-hide";
                $scope.msgClass = "text-error icon-remove";
                $scope.message = "Not Available";
            }
        }).error(function(data, status) {
            alert("Failure");
        });
    }
}
```

Whenever this checkEmail is called it is a **HTTP Bad request(400)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be because you have two `jClientSessionId` and no `jUserSessionId` in the `@RequestMapping ({jClientSessionId}/{jClientSessionId})?`

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `@ResponseBody` annotation on your `checkName` method, if your controller is not annotated as `@RestController`.